# Adding My own SOAP Headers on receiving request

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>user|pass</wsse:Username>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Above is my SOAP message header.

Im creating a cxf proxy route like below

```
from(cxf:bean:proxyEndpoint)
    .bean(SOAPHeaderAppender.class)
    .to(cxf:bean:realEndpoint)
```

Client should able to send request without `SOAPHeaders`. I would like to create and append `SOAPHeaders` in `SOAPHeaderAppender` class before sending the request to `realEndpoint`. If someone done this please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cxf interceptors should help you, see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html.

Maybe http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Adding-SOAPHeader-using-an-Interceptor-td567851.html is a good example for you.

Comment: Yes this solution works for projects using Objects like Person and im also doing same in my one of the projects. In middleware systems, there should not be any objects used in it, In that case any suggestion what should i do??